# Searching a given point in a collection in constant time

Tags: c#, algorithm, computational-geometry

Given a collection of points and a point P. Find if the point P exists in the collection in constant time. And the search should be approximate. 
For eg: 10, 20 and 11, 20 should be treated as same points. There should be some threshold say 1. 
I am using C#. The current implementation uses a Dictionary. My point class has overridden the Equals and GetHashCode() methods. The GetHashCode method always returns a 1. Which means that everything is put into the same bucket, which will make the search exhaustive. The current implementation does not use hash-power effectively. I am not able to figure out a hash function or any other way to get this done.

Comment: your problem basically translate to "Check if a given item exists in a given collection of N items in constant time". If you found a solution please be sure to let me know. This is going to be the next generation algorithm that will change the world

Comment: Writing a hash function is easy.  Look up FNV1A.  Writing a constant-time search algorithm is not easy.

Comment: With approximations, is it still easy? I want points to be similar even if they are some THRESHOLD apart.

Comment: Hash functions are not used for purposes of comparisons, in any language.

Comment: For example (10, 20) and (11, 20) should be considered equal. I suppose (11, 20) and (12, 20) should be considered equal too. But (10, 20) and (12, 20) are not equal, because they are too far apart. So this is not possible. (You get a situation where A and B must be in the same bucket, B and C must be in the same bucket, but A and C must be in different buckets). What you can do is: do several searches when you search for a point. You search for the point and for "adjacent" points.

Comment: Yes it violates total order.

Comment: So, is there any other way to solve the above problem other than the solution stated in the question?

Comment: Well, one could turn the coordinates into a single number that can be used to index/order the collection. One could then divide and conquer, which would result in a [relatively] constant search time. The threshold can be applied to the difference between the indexes.

Comment: @JuanRomero can you please elaborate.

Comment: Figure out a hash, like you said. For instance, add the two numbers. Use that to order your collection. Then look for the point based on this index. Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: I can't really imagine how you could satisfy the vicinity checking requirement with a hash code. A hash throws away information, so simply by the pigeonhole principle it seems impossible to come up with any way to "hash" a continuous 2D domain that doesn't bias you towards a grid in some way.

Depending on what your proximity metric is (radius?) it is probably still possible to do this in constant time with the appropriate choice of data structure.

Comment: What about hashing you points according to a spatial grid (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve). Alternatively, but more complex you can use Locality Sensitive Hashing (http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring05/cos598E/bib/p253-datar.pdf)

Comment: @SaiBot finding values with hash function takes constant time but Hashing does not take constant time . It's linear in the length of string . It is impossible that such an algrithm exist whose complexity is constant.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim the question is what you want to scale constant with. You are right, hashing is not constant in the lenght of the string. But for a given string length, it is constant in the number of elements.

Comment: It should be constant with respect to the number of elements or points. It will also do if it is not constant. It's just that I want it as fast as possible.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(5))`  your method now runs in constant time

Comment: This question is similar to, but not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46872807/56778. You might find some insight (although no definitive answer) over there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to let the definition of "approximate" be somewhat fuzzy, there is a simple approach that performs in `O(1)`.

Here is a picture.  Draw yourself a grid.  Draw boxes on the even lines.  Draw boxes of a different color on the odd line.  What you'll do is hash every point to its even box and its odd box.  Anything close enough will be in one of those.  The definition of close enough will vary widely depending where you are relative to your grid.